# Creating a partial view that contains a button that opens up a dialog window in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

My overall goal is to create a plug-able notes widget that can be placed on any primary view throughout my site. I imagine the widget itself being a single button 'Notes' which will open up a Kendo Window that has a simple form inside of it to add a note.

Here is the code I currently have:

**_NotesPartial.cshtml:**
As you can see there is no JavaScript to open the window here because you can't really put JavaScript in a PartialView in ASP.NET MVC from what I understand. However, it would be ideal to package everything into one place.

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.Shared.NoteViewModel

<button id="open" class="btn btn-primary">Notes</button>

@{Html.Kendo().Window()
                .Name("window")
                .Width(630)
                .Height(315)
                .Draggable()
                .Resizable()
                .Title("Notes")
                .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Refresh().Maximize().Close())
                .Content(@<text>
        <form asp-action="_NotesPartial">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>NoteViewModel</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Subject" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Content" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="4">
                        </textarea><span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </text>)
        .Render();
}
```

**PrimaryView.cshtml**

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_NotesPartial")

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#open").click(function (e) {
            $("#window").data("kendoWindow").open;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here are the problems that I am having:

1. I am having trouble getting the window to even open because I am getting errors saying 'Cannot read property 'open' of undefined'. This meaning that the js in the primary view isn't finding the kendo window.
2. I am wondering why [Telerik documentation recommends](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/window/overview#using-htmlbeginform-inside-a-window) calling .Render() on the window. This makes the form content show on the PrimaryView page by default when I want it hidden by default.
3. Is there a better way to make a plug-able widget in ASP.NET MVC. I am debating on whether the button to open the window should be part of the Partial View or in the PrimaryView even though I want everything packaged together as much as possible.

I am also wondering if I should be creating a standard view instead of a Partial View and somehow loading the standard view into a kendo window.

Regardless of what kind of dialog window I am using am I on the right track to creating a plug-gable notes dialog that can be placed on any page of the website?

This is kind of frustrating for me because in ASP.NET Webforms I can create a UserControl that can do this with no problem.

Comment: Is your `Html.Kendo()` code generating `id="window"`?

Comment: "you can't really put JavaScript in a PartialView " - you may want to research where you got that impression from... There is really no restriction of this kind (whether adding script in the middle of the page is good approach or not is separate question).

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes my Html.Kendo() code is supposed to generate id="window". Now on page load I am getting the following error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined as soon as the page loads... If I remove my custom script tag and js the error doesn't happen. It could have something to do with the way Kendo is trying to function vs where the jquery is being added to the page. I followed this documentation for setup: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-6/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can place a JavaScript script in a partial view. Just place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
</script>
```

in the partial. I don't know is it recommended, but it's certainly possible and working. The problem arises when you will try to put many same partials on the page.

Comment: Hmm so I added the javascript back to the partial view and I am now getting the following error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' when even loading the page. This means that the partial can't find jquery but I am using the new default ASP.NET 5 MVC6 template which has an _Layout.cshtml page which loads all of my scripts. I also inspected the page in chrome and saw that all of the proper scripts are loading from my lib folder.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Include your jQuery script files at the top of the page (or - better - master page), like this `<head>....@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")....</head>`

Comment: I think your right but I believe by putting .Deferred() at the bottom of my Kendo Window declaration it should make it so it renders after the jquery scripts. I setup with this documentation specifically for mvc6... http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-6/getting-started